# Disable Integrated Windows Authentication in chromium via arguments

Tags: chromium

This one has stop to work:

```
--auth-server-whitelist="_"
```

Any other ideas?

My corporation uses SSO login, but to run some automation tests locally, I need to use other user.
I'm using CodeceptJS framework. Incognito mode does not help.

Comment: It looks like they have removed that switch from Chromium. I couldn't find that switch in the Chromium source code. That's probably why it's not working. You can enable logging in Chrome and check the logs for more info: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging/

Comment: Thank you for checking. How logs can help me?

Comment: You might see invalid argument or switch in the logs